# How to create and deploy an endpoint with Directus?

Tags: directus

I have a nooby Directus question :

### How to create an endpoint and attach it to my project ?

I try to follow the doc in vain :

##### Create a directus project

1. `npm init directus-project example-project`

- SQLite / Admin / Password

2. `cd example-project; npx directus start`
3. I can access directus admin at `http://0.0.0.0:8055/admin/content`
4. CTRL+C

##### Create an endpoint

1. `cd ..`, going away of my directus project, `npm init directus-extension`
2. endpoint / demo-directus-endpoint / javascript
3. Modifying endpoint `/` to `/hello` in src/index
4. `cd demo-directus-endpoint; npm run build`

##### Deploy extensions inside directus project

https://docs.directus.io/extensions/creating-extensions/

```
To deploy your extension, you have to move the output from the dist/ folder into your project's ./extensions/<extension-folder>/<extension-name>/ folder. <extension-folder> has to be replaced by the extension type in plural form (e.g. interfaces). <extension-name> should be replaced with the name of your extension.
```

1. `cd ../example-project`
2. `mkdir ./extensions/endpoints/demo`
3. `cp -R ../demo-directus-endpoint/dist/index.js ./extensions/endpoints/demo`

index.js looks like this :

`"use strict";module.exports=e=>{e.get("/hello",((e,l)=>l.send("Hello, World!")))};`

4. `npx directus start`

```
17:43:40 ✨ Loaded extensions: demo
17:43:40 ⚠️  PUBLIC_URL should be a full URL
17:43:40 ⚠️  Spatialite isn't installed. Geometry type support will be limited.
17:43:40 ✨ Server started at http://0.0.0.0:8055
```

5. Trying to get url `http://0.0.0.0:8055/hello`

`curl http://0.0.0.0:8055/hello` => `{"errors":[{"message":"Route /hello doesn't exist.","extensions":{"code":"ROUTE_NOT_FOUND"}}]}`

```
17:43:55 ✨ request completed GET 404 /hello 8ms
```

What to do in order to get `Hello, World!` when `curl http://0.0.0.0:8055/hello` ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer found
curl http://0.0.0.0:8055/demo/hello => Hello, World!

Comment: This was helpful. It seems the URL is `/{extension-name}/{endpoint-name}`.

Comment: Thank you, Dimitri, for sharing of this information! Unfortunately documentation of Directus is not complete at this time...

Comment: Not working for me. I created index.js file at /extensions/endpoints/carts and registered GET endpoint with "/" path, and so when I hit localhost:8055/carts, I just get 404

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, there might be an issue with the `/dist` in the extension.

I advise you to move the `index.js` that is in the `/dist` and place it at the root of the extension folder.

Then, in the `package.json`, you will need to modify the path by removing the `dist/index.js`.

```json
"directus:extension": {
  "type": "endpoint",
  "path": "index.js",
  "source": "src/index.ts",
  "host": "^10.3.4"
},
```

This should resolve the issue for some people, especially if you are using Docker for Directus.